# Clickable json items

Tags: php, ajax, json

Once I posted data using PHP and Ajax, I get the result using json:

page1.php ==> post data to page2.php

so I get the data and display on page1.php, something like:

```
<a class="closeIt">close me</a>
```

once I click on "close me" I should get the id:

```
$('.closeIt').click(function(){
        var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(clicked);
    });
```

but nothing is displayed, however if I put all together on 1 single page, the code works great

Thx for your help

Comment: Typo? Chance `class="closeit"` to `class="closeIt"`

Comment: sorry RienNeVaPlus, that was only a typping error

Comment: is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: I do not know the details of your code, or when you are adding this code, but try using the .on function `.on("click", function(){...});` and see if that works.

Comment: Is the jQuery call to listen for click added at the same time as the element, or before?

Answer (score -1):

Just you have to set the id attribute of your link:

```
<a class="closeIt" id="someId">close me</a>
```

Comment: if I added this code: .on("click", function(){...});

I have this error:

TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
     
 
$('.closeIt').on('click',function(){

Comment: @Ktash: I have the code for closing item then the other code for getting items to be closed